# How to Record Video Using Front and Back Camera and still keep recording?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video, avfoundation

I'm using AVFoundation. I wanna to record video using both (front and Back side) camera. I record video on one side when i change the camera mode back to front, the camera still freeze. Is it possible to record video continuously on both side.

Sample Code:

```
- (void) startup
{
 if (_session == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Starting up server");

    self.isCapturing = NO;
    self.isPaused = NO;
    _currentFile = 0;
    _discont = NO;

    // create capture device with video input
    _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    AVCaptureDevice *backCamera = [self frontCamera];

    AVCaptureDeviceInput* input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:backCamera error:nil];
    [_session addInput:input];

    // audio input from default mic
    AVCaptureDevice* mic = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput* micinput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:mic error:nil];
    [_session addInput:micinput];

    // create an output for YUV output with self as delegate
    _captureQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.softcraftsystems.comss", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* videoout = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [videoout setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_captureQueue];
    NSDictionary* setcapSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                                    nil];
    videoout.videoSettings = setcapSettings;
    [_session addOutput:videoout];
    _videoConnection = [videoout connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    // find the actual dimensions used so we can set up the encoder to the same.
    NSDictionary* actual = videoout.videoSettings;
    _cy = [[actual objectForKey:@"Height"] integerValue];
    _cx = [[actual objectForKey:@"Width"] integerValue];

    AVCaptureAudioDataOutput* audioout = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
    [audioout setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_captureQueue];
    [_session addOutput:audioout];
    _audioConnection = [audioout connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    // for audio, we want the channels and sample rate, but we can't get those from audioout.audiosettings on ios, so
    // we need to wait for the first sample

    // start capture and a preview layer
    [_session startRunning];

    _preview = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
    _preview.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
   }
  }

  - (AVCaptureDevice *)frontCamera
  {
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
    if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
        return device;
    }
  }
  return nil;
 }

 - (AVCaptureDevice *)backCamera
 {
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
    if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
        return device;
    }
}
return nil;
}

- (void) startupFront
{
_session = nil;
[_session stopRunning];
if (_session == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Starting up server");

    self.isCapturing = NO;
    self.isPaused = NO;
    _currentFile = 0;
    _discont = NO;

    // create capture device with video input
    _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    AVCaptureDevice *backCamera = [self backCamera];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput* input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:backCamera error:nil];
    [_session addInput:input];

    // audio input from default mic
    AVCaptureDevice* mic = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput* micinput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:mic error:nil];
    [_session addInput:micinput];

    // create an output for YUV output with self as delegate
    _captureQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.softcraftsystems.comss", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* videoout = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [videoout setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_captureQueue];
    NSDictionary* setcapSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                                    nil];
    videoout.videoSettings = setcapSettings;
    [_session addOutput:videoout];
    _videoConnection = [videoout connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    // find the actual dimensions used so we can set up the encoder to the same.
    NSDictionary* actual = videoout.videoSettings;
    _cy = [[actual objectForKey:@"Height"] integerValue];
    _cx = [[actual objectForKey:@"Width"] integerValue];

    AVCaptureAudioDataOutput* audioout = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
    [audioout setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_captureQueue];
    [_session addOutput:audioout];
    _audioConnection = [audioout connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    // for audio, we want the channels and sample rate, but we can't get those from audioout.audiosettings on ios, so
    // we need to wait for the first sample

    // start capture and a preview layer
    [_session startRunning];

    _preview = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
    _preview.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
   }
   }

  - (void) startCapture
  {
   @synchronized(self)
    {
    if (!self.isCapturing)
    {
        NSLog(@"starting capture");

        // create the encoder once we have the audio params
        _encoder = nil;
        self.isPaused = NO;
        _discont = NO;
        _timeOffset = CMTimeMake(0, 0);
        self.isCapturing = YES;
     }
     }
   }

 - (void) stopCapture
 {
@synchronized(self)
{
    if (self.isCapturing)
    {
        NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"capture%d.mp4", _currentFile];
        NSString* path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
        NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        _currentFile++;

        // serialize with audio and video capture

        self.isCapturing = NO;
        dispatch_async(_captureQueue, ^{
            [_encoder finishWithCompletionHandler:^{
                self.isCapturing = NO;
                _encoder = nil;
                ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
                [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                    NSLog(@"save completed");
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
                }];
            }];
        });
    }
}
 }

 - (void) pauseCapture
 {
@synchronized(self)
{
    if (self.isCapturing)
    {
        NSLog(@"Pausing capture");
        self.isPaused = YES;
        _discont = YES;
    }
}
 }

    - (void) resumeCapture
   {
  @synchronized(self)
{
    if (self.isPaused)
    {
        NSLog(@"Resuming capture");
        self.isPaused = NO;
    }
}
  }

    - (CMSampleBufferRef) adjustTime:(CMSampleBufferRef) sample by:(CMTime) offset
 {
CMItemCount count;
CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfoArray(sample, 0, nil, &count);
CMSampleTimingInfo* pInfo = malloc(sizeof(CMSampleTimingInfo) * count);
CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfoArray(sample, count, pInfo, &count);
for (CMItemCount i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    pInfo[i].decodeTimeStamp = CMTimeSubtract(pInfo[i].decodeTimeStamp, offset);
    pInfo[i].presentationTimeStamp = CMTimeSubtract(pInfo[i].presentationTimeStamp, offset);
}
CMSampleBufferRef sout;
CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming(nil, sample, count, pInfo, &sout);
free(pInfo);
return sout;
 }

 - (void) setAudioFormat:(CMFormatDescriptionRef) fmt
 {
const AudioStreamBasicDescription *asbd = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(fmt);
_samplerate = asbd->mSampleRate;
_channels = asbd->mChannelsPerFrame;
 }

  - (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
 {
BOOL bVideo = YES;

@synchronized(self)
{
    if (!self.isCapturing  || self.isPaused)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (connection != _videoConnection)
    {
        bVideo = NO;
    }
    if ((_encoder == nil) && !bVideo)
    {
        CMFormatDescriptionRef fmt = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer);
        [self setAudioFormat:fmt];
        NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"capture%d.mp4", _currentFile];
        NSString* path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
        _encoder = [VideoEncoder encoderForPath:path Height:_cy width:_cx channels:_channels samples:_samplerate];
    }
    if (_discont)
    {
        if (bVideo)
        {
            return;
        }
        _discont = NO;
        // calc adjustment
        CMTime pts = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
        CMTime last = bVideo ? _lastVideo : _lastAudio;
        if (last.flags & kCMTimeFlags_Valid)
        {
            if (_timeOffset.flags & kCMTimeFlags_Valid)
            {
                pts = CMTimeSubtract(pts, _timeOffset);
            }
            CMTime offset = CMTimeSubtract(pts, last);
            NSLog(@"Setting offset from %s", bVideo?"video": "audio");
            NSLog(@"Adding %f to %f (pts %f)", ((double)offset.value)/offset.timescale, ((double)_timeOffset.value)/_timeOffset.timescale, ((double)pts.value/pts.timescale));

            // this stops us having to set a scale for _timeOffset before we see the first video time
            if (_timeOffset.value == 0)
            {
                _timeOffset = offset;
            }
            else
            {
                _timeOffset = CMTimeAdd(_timeOffset, offset);
            }
        }
        _lastVideo.flags = 0;
        _lastAudio.flags = 0;
    }

    // retain so that we can release either this or modified one
    CFRetain(sampleBuffer);

    if (_timeOffset.value > 0)
    {
        CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
        sampleBuffer = [self adjustTime:sampleBuffer by:_timeOffset];
    }

    // record most recent time so we know the length of the pause
    CMTime pts = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
    CMTime dur = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer);
    if (dur.value > 0)
    {
        pts = CMTimeAdd(pts, dur);
    }
    if (bVideo)
    {
        _lastVideo = pts;
    }
    else
    {
        _lastAudio = pts;
    }
}

// pass frame to encoder
[_encoder encodeFrame:sampleBuffer isVideo:bVideo];
CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
 }

 - (void) shutdown
 {
NSLog(@"shutting down server");
if (_session)
{
    [_session stopRunning];
    _session = nil;
}
[_encoder finishWithCompletionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Capture completed");
}];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me. it is not possible, continue recording when we switch the camera,
because, there resolution and quality difference between them, a video can have only one resolution and quality throughout the video.
and secondly, every time you switch between camera it'll alloc and initialize the camera.
unfortunately its not  possible according to me.
but if you find solution, do tell me please.

Comment: Did you see 2camshoot app.